# nodejs javascript find with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I have a queue of players and wanted to get the first player that met one of my two conditions, but I am unsure how to do that.

First I get the value of a player (mmr)
and wanted to get one (only one) player from the queue that had 5% more or less of this value

My condition I think is this to get 5% more or less:

```
  const condition = (5/100)*playerOne.mmr + playerOne.mmr
  const condition2 = (5/100)*playerOne.mmr - playerOne.mmr
```

my function:

```
makeMatch(playerOne) {
  // make matched players
  const condition = (5/100)*playerOne.mmr + playerOne.mmr
  const condition2 = (5/100)*playerOne.mmr - playerOne.mmr
  const player = playerOne;
  const matchedPlayer = this.players.find();
  // remove matched players from this.players
  this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
  // return new Match with matched players
  return new Match(matchedPlayers);
}
```

I have questions as I would get 5% more or less within my find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function it details this use case. Here's the line that you would want for the desired result.

```
const matchedPlayer = this.players.find((playerTwo) => playerTwo.mmr > condition || playerTwo.mmr > condition2);
```

Comment: I think that's what I wanted, thanks bro
in case he goes looking for the first one between 5% down and 5% up?

Comment: If you want to find a value between the two conditions just change the condition in the find to `playerTwo.mmr < condition && playerTwo.mmr > condition2`

Comment: Remember to mark their answer as correct, if it helped solved your issue.

Comment: @Shimmy568 thanks a lot brow, Could you just ask me one more question?
I'm trying to check if my queue has a player, but I'm a little lost

ie before creating match I wanted to check if that player is in my queue

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
if (player.condition1 > condition1*0.95 && player.condition1 < condition1*1.05) {
   // then you keep the player
} else {
   // else you remove it from the list
}
```

> Also, I would highly reccomend you to give better identifiers to the variables. Instead of condition1, something like `age`, `height`, `weight`.